# Usage of 'self' keyword inside a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following sample code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.scores = args

    def calculate_sum(self):
        return sum(self.scores)

scores = list(map(int, input().split()))
s = Student(scores)
print("sum:", s.calculate_sum())
```

When I call this method, I get the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

However, if I remove 'self' keyword from the attribute scores, it works fine:

```
def calculate_sum(self):
    print(sum(scores))
```

Note: Input is space-separated integers in a line. Eg. 100 67 78

Would somebody be kind enough to explain why this happens and also what the TypeError message means (that I am adding int to a list?!)?

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Is your `scores` list perhaps a *list of lists*?

Comment: `self.scores` and `scores` are two completely different references that accomplish different goals. Try removing the `sum()` call and looking at the output. You should see two different things showing up

Comment: @VictorC.: no, mind that sum first starts with an *implicit 0*. So `sum([[1,4]])` will error.

Comment: @NieDzejkob I added the full code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem scores is a list of integers.

Comment: @calico_ I see that that adding self. somehow makes it a list of list but I do not really understand why this happens

Comment: @KanishkDugar: but you use `*args`, so you get a 1-tuple with the list...

Comment: @KanishkDugar I think the indentation makes python think it's not a function but a method.

Comment: @KanishkDugar you are doing `self.scores = args`, but args is a list of arguments, so you either need to change it to do `def __init__(self, scores): self.scores = scores` or `def __init__(self, *args): self.scores = args[0]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are right! I do get a tuple with a list when I use 'self'. But again what is the difference between using and not using 'self'?

Comment: @NieDzejkob You are absolutely right! Thanks for pointing it out. BTW 'scores' work because it is a global variable :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, 'scores' is sent as a list and not as *args. So that was incorrect, which made self.scores a tuple with a list.

Secondly, it worked with just 'scores' and not 'self.scores' because 'scores' is a global variable as well, which is a list.

Thanks @NieDzejkob and @WillemVanOnsem for helping me figure out this goof-up.